# How to find react-map-gl-draw icons className

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, react-map-gl

I'm using the react-map-gl-draw library to draw polygons on the map. I would like to find out the className for the icons of react-map-gl-draw.

For example,  `className="mapbox-gl-draw_ctrl-draw-btn mapbox-gl-draw_trash"` will give me a button with trash can icon. I was wondering where can I find other icons' className.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of buttons you can add, these are your options:

```
.mapbox-gl-draw_point {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">%3Cpath d="m10 2c-3.3 0-6 2.7-6 6s6 9 6 9 6-5.7 6-9-2.7-6-6-6zm0 2c2.1 0 3.8 1.7 3.8 3.8 0 1.5-1.8 3.9-2.9 5.2h-1.7c-1.1-1.4-2.9-3.8-2.9-5.2-.1-2.1 1.6-3.8 3.7-3.8z"/>%3C/svg>');
}
.mapbox-gl-draw_polygon {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">%3Cpath d="m15 12.3v-4.6c.6-.3 1-1 1-1.7 0-1.1-.9-2-2-2-.7 0-1.4.4-1.7 1h-4.6c-.3-.6-1-1-1.7-1-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2 0 .7.4 1.4 1 1.7v4.6c-.6.3-1 1-1 1.7 0 1.1.9 2 2 2 .7 0 1.4-.4 1.7-1h4.6c.3.6 1 1 1.7 1 1.1 0 2-.9 2-2 0-.7-.4-1.4-1-1.7zm-8-.3v-4l1-1h4l1 1v4l-1 1h-4z"/>%3C/svg>');
}
.mapbox-gl-draw_line {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">%3Cpath d="m13.5 3.5c-1.4 0-2.5 1.1-2.5 2.5 0 .3 0 .6.2.9l-3.8 3.8c-.3-.1-.6-.2-.9-.2-1.4 0-2.5 1.1-2.5 2.5s1.1 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5-1.1 2.5-2.5c0-.3 0-.6-.2-.9l3.8-3.8c.3.1.6.2.9.2 1.4 0 2.5-1.1 2.5-2.5s-1.1-2.5-2.5-2.5z"/>%3C/svg>');
}
.mapbox-gl-draw_trash {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">%3Cpath d="M10,3.4 c-0.8,0-1.5,0.5-1.8,1.2H5l-1,1v1h12v-1l-1-1h-3.2C11.5,3.9,10.8,3.4,10,3.4z M5,8v7c0,1,1,2,2,2h6c1,0,2-1,2-2V8h-2v5.5h-1.5V8h-3 v5.5H7V8H5z"/>%3C/svg>');
}
.mapbox-gl-draw_uncombine {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">%3Cpath d="m12 2c-.3 0-.5.1-.7.3l-1 1c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4l1 1c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l1-1c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4l-1-1c-.2-.2-.4-.3-.7-.3zm4 4c-.3 0-.5.1-.7.3l-1 1c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4l1 1c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l1-1c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4l-1-1c-.2-.2-.4-.3-.7-.3zm-7 1c-1 0-1 1-.5 1.5.3.3 1 1 1 1l-1 1s-.5.5 0 1 1 0 1 0l1-1 1 1c.5.5 1.5.5 1.5-.5v-4zm-5 3c-.3 0-.5.1-.7.3l-1 1c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4l4.9 4.9c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l1-1c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4l-4.9-4.9c-.1-.2-.4-.3-.7-.3z"/>%3C/svg>');
}
.mapbox-gl-draw_combine {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">%3Cpath d="M12.1,2c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.3l-1,1c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l4.9,4.9c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l1-1 c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4l-4.9-4.9C12.6,2.1,12.3,2,12.1,2z M8,8C7,8,7,9,7.5,9.5c0.3,0.3,1,1,1,1l-1,1c0,0-0.5,0.5,0,1s1,0,1,0l1-1l1,1 C11,13,12,13,12,12V8H8z M4,10c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.3l-1,1c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l1,1c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l1-1c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4 l-1-1C4.5,10.1,4.3,10,4,10z M8,14c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.7,0.3l-1,1c-0.4,0.4-0.4,1,0,1.4l1,1c0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.4,0l1-1 c0.4-0.4,0.4-1,0-1.4l-1-1C8.5,14.1,8.3,14,8,14z"/>%3C/svg>');
}
```

It seems like everything else is overriding default Mapbox styling.

Here's the [full css file](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/main/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css) of classes from `react-map-gl-draw` if you want to check it out.